# Creating a two state button in Android

Tags: android, button, state

I'm trying to understand how to make a button that latches onto a value when it is pressed, when it's pressed again it unlatches.

My method for this is as follows:

```
boolean r1 = false;
boolean r2 = true;
private boolean flipFlop(boolean read, int i)
{
    if(read == true)
    {
        if (r1 == true && r2 == false)
        {
            r1 = false;
            r2 = true;
        }
        else if(r1 == false && r2 == true)
        {
            r1 = true;
            r2 = false;
        }   


    }

    return r1;
}
```

flipFlop method is called under onTouch, like so:

```
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motion)
        {

            boolean pressCheck = false;

            switch(motion.getAction())
            {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            {

                pressCheck = flipFlop(view.isPressed(), 1);
                textView.setText("State is: " + pressCheck);
            }

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            {
                pressCheck = flipFlop(view.isPressed(), 1);
                textView.setText("State is: " + pressCheck);

            }
            }
            return false;

        }
```

When clicking once, the state is set to false and doesn't change.
When double-clicking, it flipflops between the two states. Why is that?

Also, when I tried making it with an array to hold the states, it latched to true and Doesn't change when double-tapping:

```
private boolean[][] latch = {{false, false, false}, {true, true, true}};

public boolean flipFlop(boolean read, int i)
{
    if(read == true)
    {
        if(latch[i][2] == true && latch[i][1] == false)
        {
            latch[i][1] = true;
            latch[i][2] = false;
        }
        else if(latch[i][2] == false && latch[i][1] == true)
        {
            latch[i][1] = false;
            latch[i][2] = true;
        }
    }

    return latch[i][1];
```

}

Comment: Have you tried using the built-in [`ToggleButton`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ToggleButton.html)?

Comment: what if u use [Toggle Button](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ToggleButton.html) widget ? won't that work for you ?

Comment: No, I forgot to mention that the widget won't do the trick this time.

Comment: Can you be more specific regarding what it is about the existing `CompoundButton` classes that is not meeting your needs?

Comment: I'm trying to make it work together with the reading of a digital input on a microcontroller.